# Best way of adding CSS which can be manipulated by the user via theme option panels?

Tags: php, functions, css

I thought about adding it as inline CSS with code from the `functions.php`
(not really sure how to do it).

Something like this:

```
function addcss() {
   background: $this_is_the_css_value;
}
```

I would like to know that. But if there's is a better option (without adding inline CSS). I would like to know it too.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7048/best-practices-for-a-style-css-based-theme-options-page

Comment: downvoted and flagged as dupe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to create a "CSS" file from PHP. In other words, create a file, call it something like `style.css.php`, and at the beginning of the file put:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css");
```

Then, link that file in the head of your theme file. Because the `style.css.php` file is a PHP file, anything you can do in a normal PHP file can be done in this file. As such, you can pull theme option values from the database and use them. For example:

```
#header{
    background: <?php echo get_option('my-header-background-color'); ?>
}
```

Of course, you need to get the options into the database first, but since your question didn't address that, I won't go into it here.

Comment: Thanks! I did the database part with this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-create-a-better-wordpress-options-panel/comment-page-2/#comments

Comment: The best way is to write the file, after saving in the admin option panel to a fixed .css file and then enqueue that file. You don't want to re-run php for EACH page load ... (for the same css output). See other answers on the same question.

Answer (score 2):

Generating CSS from PHP means it has to run that code for each pageload, if it is possible generate a static CSS file and then enqueue it.

So... See:

[How do I add CSS options to my plugin without using inline styles?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/how-do-i-add-css-options-to-my-plugin-without-using-inline-styles) or

[Best way to inject css into admin_head in plugins?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10477/best-way-to-inject-css-into-admin-head-in-plugins) or

[How to add CSS style sheet dynamically in wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/how-to-add-css-style-sheet-dynamically-in-wordpress)

Comment: Also this one, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7048/best-practices-for-a-style-css-based-theme-options-page

Comment: +1 for the great suggestion! My preferred option would actually be to place the custom CSS in the head, which would avoid writing a file and doing the css.php business. As the OP did not want inline CSS, I thought the css.php trick would be ok, but I also really like your solution. The only downside to it, in my opinion, is potential issues with file permissions that cause difficulties writing the file.